# How to build Linux on ARM devices?

Tags: arm

I apologize if this is the incorrect place to ask this but I am struggling to find where I should post this. I am a long time Linux fanboy, its all I use. For some time I have been putting together OS's on ARM devices but in a terribly junky way. Lets say for example I want Alpine OS on a device. I will look for the devices DTB and a prebuilt OS. I will take the boot sector from the prebuilt, and the DTB, then create an unholy union duct taping the DTB, boot and Alpine FS together to create a working OS. It does work, but I need a provided dtb and prebuilt os so someone has done everything difficult already.

So my question is, how is the first OS built? If you handed me an RPI (or any other device) how does one get a working kernel compiled and built? Or at the very least, how could I stop channeling my inner frnkenstien and stop creating these monsters?

Comment: The best suggestion I can give is to take a look at the "Linux From Scratch" project.

Comment: It sure looks interesting, thank you I think this is probably a better place to start. Not exactly ARM related but knowing more about how everything works is a good place to start. Thank you!

Comment: As you make your LFS, you'll learn along the way how to compile and, optionally, how to compile for different architectures. It's the best/most complete project I can think of that will get you were you seem to want to go. The LinuxQuestions forum has quite a few members that are fluent in LFS, should this site not be adequate for your needs.